# Python Script Crashes at random points

Tags: python, crash

```
import requests
import threading

url = 'example.url'

username = input('Enter Username:')

data= {
    'UserName': 'username',
    'Password': 'JJJJJJJJJ',
    'AuthMethod': 'FormsAuthentication',
}

def do_request():
    while True:
        response = requests.post(url, data=data).text
        print(response)

threads = []

for i in range(50):
    t = threading.Thread(target=do_request)
    t.daemon = True
    threads.append(t)
    
for i in range(50):
    threads[i].start()

for i in range(50):
     threads[i].join()
```

So I'm running a request script to keep attempting to log on this certain site to test certain security features, the script is meant to be run indefinitely but at some point that I don't catch the script crashes I guess and closes, for reference I'm using a VPN so that the requests aren't sent through my IP, I think the VPN might be getting too loaded or slow and at some point the script slows down and closes/crashes I honestly have no clue I've just seen it get super slow sometimes then a few minutes later it closed/crashed. Any recommendations or things I can do to prevent this? (Code might be just a little incorrect since I edited it to hide website URL and username)

Comment: You could put a try/except in do_request that logs the error and traceback.

Comment: It takes like a couple hours to crash/close that would take too long

Comment: You have code without good error detection then complain about errors .... You'll have to get that in there some time. It could be that you run out of sockets for the requests. Perhaps the OS has them in timed wait. If that's the case, you may have to throttle back requests or figure out a way to increase socket count in your OS. The error handling will tell you when to back off.

Comment: fair enough lmao just need it to be working soon ig sometimes shit takes time

Answer (score 0):

You're overloading the website in the `url` variable with 50 threads that all do `post` requests indefinitely and immediately. Depending on what the `url` is, it could take time to compute and return your post request. Using `time.sleep()` in between `post` request would be ideal. Depending on the website's implementation, they could be sending you a `HTTP 429` error for too many requests.